# How to run multiple request with axios without waiting it finish

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, asynchronous, axios

I want to make multiple requests with Axios without waiting it finish one on one.

what i want to do is, even when the first request is waiting, i want the second request is keep proccess and send the return, i dont want to waiting the first request because it will take long time..

```
async sendLog() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.proccessData === true) { 
        $nuxt.$axios.post('http://localhost/api/log/procreate', {logFile: this.form.logName})
        .then((res) => {
            this.sendLog();
        })
    }
    }, 1000);
},
async addServer() {      
   $nuxt.$axios.post('http://localhost/api/servers/create', this.form)
    .then((res) => {
      this.proccessData = false;
    }
}
```

But this code will run the next request when the current request is finished.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post multiple Axios requests at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385454/how-to-post-multiple-axios-requests-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP and Laravel when it's a question about JS/Axios?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson cause i use laravel as backend, maybe theres a setting on backend site..

Comment: Well, since it's about calling the backend, it would be odd if you needed to call the backend to get the settings for how to call the backend :-) So no, PHP and Laravel is unrelated here.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini still waiting the first finish.. what i want to do is, even when the first request is waiting, i want the second request is keep proccess and send the return, i dont want to waiting the first cause it will take long time...

Answer (score 1):

```js
const foo = async() => {
  const p1 = $nuxt.$axios.post();
  const p2 = $nuxt.$axios.post();
  const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
  // do with res1 and res2
}
```

see [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Hello @sodust, please, when you post an answer always remember to give a minimum of explanation

Comment: @Simone Rossaini my bad

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want sendLog to be processed multiple times without waiting the previous one to finish, you might choose to use interval as following

```js
async sendLog() {
  setInterval(() => {
    if (this.proccessData === true) {
      $nuxt.$axios.post('http://localhost/api/log/procreate', {
        logFile: this.form.logName
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: no problem with the method, the problem is request from method `sendlog` not proccess when request from method `addserver` still running..

Comment: I don't see any reason why request from addServer could affect the request from sendLog. Unless you are reached to the concurrent requests limit of the browser or `this.proccessData` is incorrectly setting elsewhere.