# Why is axios waiting for the previous request before executing the next one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
I am facing a serious problem and cannot find the answer
Here are my components
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Component1 from './Component1'
import Component2 from './Component2'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Component1 />
        <Component2 />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component1.jsx:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import API from './api'

let Component1 = () => {
  let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    let fetch = async () => {
      await API.one()
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
    fetch()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && 'Loading...'}
      {!isLoading && 'Loaded!'}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component1
```

Component2.jsx:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import API from './api'

let Component2 = () => {
  let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    let fetch = async () => {
      await API.two()
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
    fetch()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && 'Loading...'}
      {!isLoading && 'Loaded!'}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component2
```

api.js:

```
import * as axios from 'axios'

let instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost/`
})

let API = {
  one() {
    return instance.get('test?sleep=1').then(res => res.data)
  },
  two() {
    return instance.get('test?sleep=2').then(res => res.data)
  }
}

export default API
```

I pass the delay value in seconds and the script waits.
But in the console I see that the second component is waiting for the first to execute the command. As a result, API.one takes 1 second and API.two takes 3 seconds. It turns out that they work synchronously and until the first component returns the result, the second waits for it! What to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post multiple Axios requests at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385454/how-to-post-multiple-axios-requests-at-the-same-time)

Comment: [Works fine here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-wing-pmnu1?file=/src/index.js) . Those `sleep` params make me think you have set a server side delay

Comment: Do you see both requests made essentially at the same time when both components mount? Is the server only handling a single request at a time? I don't see any reason for the frontend code to make one component wait to do its mounting effect over the other, they should happen *basically* at the same time.

Comment: Even the all method does not solve this, requests are made in turn. Moreover, I do not need this method, I execute the API in different parts of the application.

Comment: Ok, I checked the code and realized that this is happening on firefox 88. In chromium, the request does not wait for the last one and I do not understand why

Comment: I have to play with Fast 3G or slow 3G network to simulate the behavior, and I also Disabled the cache. Maybe you can try to see if you actually have cache turned on, because it's really hard to tell the difference.

Comment: In development mode, of course, the cache is disabled. All the same, the problem is even in chrome, this is some kind of browser limitation and apparently you will have to preload all the content with one request to do it as needed

Answer (score 0):

a) `setTimeout` works

```
const Component2 = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    }, 2000)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {loading && 'loading...'}
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  )
}
```

b) `sleep` works

```
function sleep (sec) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), sec)
  })
}

const Component1 = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let fetch = async () => {
     await sleep(1000)
     setLoading(false)
    }
    fetch()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {loading && 'loading...'}
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  )
}
```

c) axios actually works

```
function sleep (sec) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(1), sec)
  })
}

const Component1 = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let fetch = async () => {
     await axios.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Wayne%27s_Pachifractal_very_large_bright.jpg')
     setLoading(false)
    }
    fetch()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {loading && 'loading....'}
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  )
}

const Component2 = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let fetch = async () => {
     await axios.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Wayne%27s_Pachifractal_very_large_bright.jpg/1597px-Wayne%27s_Pachifractal_very_large_bright.jpg')
     setLoading(false)
    }
    fetch()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {loading && 'loading....'}
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I watched the "Network tab" and see two thread starts at similar time and then ends one by one since I put a larger picture in one of the thread.

Comment: Take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-frost-e4ve9?file=/src/App.js Why is the request going in order and waiting for the previous one? I checked through curl and it's not about the server

Comment: One component with a 'for' will go one by one since you have to await for next line. However it's different than two components where there are no way to block one component initialization from another one.

Comment: I removed await but the problem persists https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-cori-hcpp4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think its your browser, my 20sleeps starts at same time, so all of them run in parallel. I thought chrome has a limit of 4threads, but I'm wrong :)

Comment: I have this on all browsers, so the problem is in my Linux. Thanks, I'll go set up