# how can i make multiple axios requests with axios.all in vue js using try and catch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to use one axios.get instead of typing it mutiple times

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
 blogs:"",
      categories: "",
      owners: ""
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/blogs").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.blogs = res.data.blogs;
    });
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/categories").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.categories = res.data.categories;
    });
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/owners").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.owners = res.data.owners;
    });
  },
 
};
</script>
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: `mounted` doesn't need to be async since none of the axios calls are awaited.

Comment: You cannot query multiple URLs with one GET request. What are you trying to do? Having those three requests is not an issue as long as the response is cached properly.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I'm trying to use axios.all to call all requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post multiple Axios requests at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385454/how-to-post-multiple-axios-requests-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @jibzy map your URLs to `axios.get()` calls (promises) and then use `Promise.all()` to assign the results to `this` properties. Or, use `axios.all()` helper.